# Yahoo Email background color and center alignment

Tags: html, css, html-email

Yahoo is ignoring the wrapper table with 100% width and background color set for an email. The background color is getting displayed as white and the content is aligning left and displaying only the inner table which is set to 600px. Previously tested emails are also having the same problem. Any help to fix this issue would be highly appreciated. Below is the sample code Im testing.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
.ReadMsgBody {width: 100%;}
.ExternalClass {width: 100%;}
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#000000; margin:0px; padding:0px;" bgcolor="#000000">
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#000000">
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#000000" style="padding:20px;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" bgcolor="#1a1a1a">
    <tr>
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:22px; padding:20px; border:1px solid #cccccc;" align="left">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</td>
    </tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: At first glance, your code looks good to me. Maybe if you include a screenshot of where it is messing up, it might help identify the cause.

Comment: Im unable to upload the screenshot image...any other way I can share the screenshot with you..

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem? I have the same and don't know what is wrong

Comment: Not yet :(, Please share if you find any!

Comment: Based off of this: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ I used background-color and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add width: 1440px on  that before  with width='600'
like this:

```
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#000000" style="padding:20px; width: 1440px">
```

That will display you mail content in the middle and not on the left side

Comment: Thank you! but if I add the width 1440px the browser is displaying a scroll bar at the bottom and the content is hiding at right side. I've to scroll right to see the content which I don't want to do. Width 800px is working for me but not 100% which it used to do before, any specific reason?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with a different header? That's the one I always use.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Also (AFAIK) you'll not be able to get rid of the white border, which means that you cannot stretch body to be 100%, there will always be a couple of white pixels gap.

Comment: Thank You! Ive tried the above header, but nosuccess. Its ok if there is some white color border remains, but here its totally ignoring the background color and wrapper width...